# Error when trying to change the height of a form

Tags: delphi

Trying to change the height of a form. In the form i'm trying to change it gives me the error:

> "Access violation at address 005B9963 in module 'M1Project.exe. Read of address 0000005C."

In other forms i can change the height fine, it's just this form. Does anyone know why this error is occuring?
Here's the code:

```
procedure TExamQuestions.RandomQuestionButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
   var
   gif:TgifImage;
   filelocation,temp:string;
   i,x,cycle,questionid,length:integer;
   questionpool: array  [0..81] of integer;
begin
   Randomize;
   cycle:=random(80)+1;
   questionid:= cycle mod x;
   currentquestion:=questionpool[questionID];
   temp:=inttostr(currentquestion);
   if temp='0' then
     temp:=inttostr(questionpool[x]);
   gif:=TgifImage.Create;
   loginmenu.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
   loginmenu.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT question from examquestions where questionID='+temp+'');
   loginmenu.ADOQuery1.Active:=true;               
      filelocation:=loginmenu.datasource1.DataSet.FieldByName('Question').AsString;
   filelocation:=('O:\Subjects\Computing\Year 13 EXEs\DButcher\A2 bant\Project = (\Program\Resources\List\'+filelocation);
   gif.loadfromfile(filelocation);
   length:=gif.Height;
   ExamQuestionPicutre.Height:=length;
   background.ClientHeight:=length;
   ExamQuestionPicutre.Picture.assign(gif);
   examquestions.Height:=length;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `examquestions` is `nil`. We cannot see where it is initialised, or as it seems, not initialised.

One imagines that `examquestions` is a global variable declared like this:

```
var
  ExamQuestions: TExamQuestions;
```

If the form was auto-created then the .dpr file would contain this line:

```
Application.CreateForm(TExamQuestions, ExamQuestions);
```

But it looks like you removed that line and have created the form manually. Which is fine, indeed a good move. But when you do that you should also remove the unhelpful global variable that the IDE added for you. It only leads to confusion like this.

In any case, you should never use a global instance variable to operate on `Self`. Replace

```
examquestions.Height:=length;
```

with

```
Height:=length;
```

And finally, you seem to have no regard at all for letter case. True, Pascal is not case-sensitive, but simply deciding to use lower case for all code that you type makes your code harder to read. Don't do that. Use Pascal case. Don't mix Pascal case with all lower case. In fact don't mix at all. Be consistent.

Comment: You should also consider another name for the local variable "length", because "Length" is also the name of an internal function.